# NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupport after launching Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, launching

I get these exceptions when opening Groovy files:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.Activator.start() of bundle org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupport
```

or

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/refactoring/formatter/GroovyIndentationService
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.editor.GroovyAutoIndentStrategy.<init>(GroovyAutoIndentStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.editor.GroovyConfiguration.getAutoEditStrategies(GroovyConfiguration.java:181)
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring (47).
...
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.Activator.start() of bundle org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.LanguageSupport
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy needs a special version of the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin.

For 3.7, the original plugin has the version `3.7.3.v2012...` but you need `3.7.3.xx-2013*`

If you start Eclipse via an "Eclipse Application" launch config, open it in the "Run Configurations" dialog. In the "Plug-ins" tab, search for "jdt.core" and activate the correct plugin.

If it's not there, remove and install the Groovy feature again.

Comment: This is still up-to-date, even 9 years later. After upgrading from Eclipse 2022-03 to 2022-06 I got the described error message. Updating the "Groovy Development Tools" Plugin from version 4.5.0.RELEASE to 4.6.0.RELEASE via Eclipse Marketplace removed that error message. :-)

Comment: @S.Doe I still get that error on 2022-06 even with Groovy Development Tools at 4.6.0.RELEASE.  I am explicitly removing that package and re-adding it in the hopes that it works.

Turns out... it didn't.  I cannot use the Groovy Editor at all. :/